# Expression must be a modifiable L-value

Tags: c, char, variable-assignment, lvalue

I have here `char text[60];`

Then I do in an `if`:

```
if(number == 2)
  text = "awesome";
else
  text = "you fail";
```

and it always said **expression must be a modifiable L-value.**

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`lvalue` means "left value" -- it should be assignable. You cannot change the value of `text` since it is an array, not a pointer.

Either declare it as char pointer (in this case it's better to declare it as `const char*`):

```
const char *text;
if(number == 2) 
    text = "awesome"; 
else 
    text = "you fail";
```

Or use strcpy:

```
char text[60];
if(number == 2) 
    strcpy(text, "awesome"); 
else 
    strcpy(text, "you fail");
```