# Concatenate two characters in c

Tags: c

How to concatenate two characters and store the result in a variable?

For example, I have 3 characters `'a'`, `'b'` and `'c'` and I need to join them together and store them in an array and later use this array as a string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char n[10];

main ()
{
    // now I want insert them in an array
    //ex: n = { a + b + c }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to access elements of array?

Comment: So store the characters in the appropriate elements of your array, followed by a string terminator.

Comment: Or use `sprintf()` (but that's awfully heavyweight for such a simple task).

Comment: A simple google search might always be helpful. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways, the following 2 methods have exactly the same results: (using your code as a starting point.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    //Given the following
    char a = 'a';
    char b = 'b';
    char c = 'c';
    
    // assignment by initializer list at time of creation
    char n1[10] = {a,b,c};
    
    //usage of a string function
    char n2[10] = {0};   //initialize  array
    sprintf(n2, "%c%c%c", a, b, c);

    return 0;
}
```

Both result in a null terminated `char` arrays, or [C strings](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm).

Answer (score 2):

Simply:

```
char a = 'a', b = 'b', c = 'c';

char str[4];
str[0] = a;
str[1] = b;
str[2] = c;
str[3] = '\0';
```

Or, if you want `str` to be stored on the heap (e.g. if you plan on returning it from a function):

```
char *str = malloc(4);
str[0] = a;
...
```

Any introductory book on C should cover this.

Answer (score 2):

An assignment similar to that can only be done when the `char` array is declared using [array initialiation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization) with a brace-enclosed list:

```
char a = 'a', b = 'b', c = 'c';
char n[10] = {a, b, c};
```

After the declaration you can't do it like this because [a `char` array is not a modifiable lvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6008733/6865932):

```
n = {a, b, c}; //error
```

To insert characters in an array that has been previously initialized, you need to either insert them one by one as exemplified [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63812559/6865932), or use some library function like `sprintf`.

```
sprintf(n, "%c%c%c", a, b, c);
```

In both of my examples the char array will be null terminated by the compiler so you can use it as a string, if you assign the characters one by one, make sure to place a null terminator at the end (`'\0'`), only then will you have a propper string.