# Using this with array of pointer in class constructor c++

Tags: c++, pointers, this

I tried to assign an array of pointer to nullptr.

```
class ToyBox
{
private:
  Toy *toyBox[5];
  int numberOfItems;

public:
  ToyBox()
  {
    this->numberOfItems = 0;
    this->toyBox = {}
  }
}
```

An error throw at *this* in *this->toyBox*:

> expression must be a modifiable lvalueC/C++(137)

Any suggestion to corrected?

Comment: `this->toyBox = {}` What do you expect it to do? Also, `Toy *toyBox[5];` is not a pointer to an array, but array of pointers, is that intended?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expression must be a modifiable L-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008733/expression-must-be-a-modifiable-l-value)

Comment: @Quimby I think the expectation of that line is given at the beginning of the question: "assign an array of pointer to nullptr." Not the best phrasing, but I believe that is supposed to mean "assign `nullptr` to the pointers in an array".

Comment: It seems to me that [What is this weird colon-member (" : ") syntax in the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor) might be useful reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only Initialize arrays in that way: [Assign a single value to array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5732852/9248466). But in the constructor you could/must use Member Initialize List:

```cpp
class ToyBox
{
private:
  Toy *toyBox[5];
  int numberOfItems;

public:
  ToyBox() :
     toyBox{nullptr}
     , numberOfItems(0)
  {
  }
};
```

---

With C++, It's better to use `std::array` instead of raw C-Array:
<sub>related: [CppCoreGuidlines: ES.27](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Res-stack)</sub>

```cpp
class ToyBox
{
private:
  std::array<Toy*, 5> toyBox;
  int numberOfItems;

public:
  ToyBox() :
     toyBox({nullptr})
     , numberOfItems(0)
  {
  }
};
```

Or (I think) better:

```cpp
  ToyBox() : numberOfItems(0)
  {
    std::fill(toyBox.begin(), toyBox.end(), nullptr);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, very detailed answer!

Comment: Since `ToyBox` tracks the number of items, `std::vector` might be a better choice than `std::array`. In fact, an even better approach might be `using ToyBox = std::vector<Toy*>`.

Comment: @JaMiT It is fixed code, I have no choice mate :(

Comment: @TanNguyen Since you are stuck with "fixed code", it doesn't really matter to you what alternatives are mentioned, does it? Besides, the goal of this site it to be a repository of knowledge (in question-and-answer format) for future visitors. It's just a (often occurring) bonus when a good answer for future visitors happens to also help the original asker. Improving an answer for the benefit of future readers is good. (In my mind, the improvement would still mention `std::array` as an improvement, then mention `std::vector` as the next step up.)